# How to make a Password that leads into the application

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a pass lock screen that leads into a textedit type program but With may code it goes into start of code (where Security is) but doesn't continue after my first "if"  statement it just stays blank, Please help try and fix it i am a new programmer learning python and i need the help thank you

```
from Tkinter import*
from tkFileDialog import*
import time
def Security ():
    Username = ("jtreleaven")
    Password = ("Hammer2963")
    inputUser = input("Username: ")
    if inputUser == Username:
        inputPass = input ("Password: ")
        if inputPass == ("Hammer2963"):
            print ("")
        else:
            print ("Invalid Username or Password")
            Security("Try Again")
            time.sleep(5);
    else:
        print ("Invalid Username or Password")
        Security("Try Again")
        time.sleep(5);
Security()

filename = None

def newFile():
    global filename
    filename = "Untitled"
    text.delete(0.0, END)

def saveFile():
    global filename
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(t)
    f.close()

def saveAs():
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
    except:
        showerror(title="oops!", message="Unable to save file...")

def openFile():
    f = askopenfile(mode = 'r')
    t = f.read()
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, t)

root = Tk()
root.title("My Python Text Editor")
root.minsize(width = 400, height = 400)
root.maxsize(width = 400, height = 400)

text = Text(root, width = 400, height = 400)
text.pack()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label='New', command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label='Open', command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label='Save', command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label = 'Save As...', command = saveAs)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label = "Quit", command = root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label = 'File', menu = filemenu)

root.config(menu = menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using Python 2.7 as you are importing `Tkinter` with capital T. The problem here is that you are managing the user entry with `input` (Python 3) when it has to be `raw_input` so it can compare two strings.

I also moved the `sleep` function before calling the `Security` function again as this what you probably wanted.

Change the `Security` function to this, and it would work.

```
def Security ():
    Username = ("jtreleaven")
    Password = ("Hammer2963")
    inputUser = raw_input("Username: ")
    if inputUser == Username:
        inputPass = raw_input ("Password: ")
        if inputPass == ("Hammer2963"):
            print ("")
        else:
            print ("Invalid Username or Password")
            print ("Try Again")
            time.sleep(5)
            Security()
    else:
        print ("Invalid Username or Password")
        print ("Try Again")
        time.sleep(5)
        Security()
```

Comment: It'd be better if you mention/correct `TypeError: Security() takes no arguments (1 given)` when wrong username or password given.

Comment: Thanks @Lafexlos I didn't notice that.

Comment: Glad it works, Please, accept the answer by ticking the "V" of the question.